# How to give permission to application private data(/data/data/package_name/ in android > KK

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.3-jelly-bean

As part of my application, i am storing images and videos under /data/data/app_package/ path. Same images i will dispaly as thumbnails. When user clicks any image, i have to create ACTION_VIEW intent and start the activity.

But  when i select any app from activity chooser, the image/video is not getting displayed and file not found toast is shown.

**How can we provide access to other apps to read** the images/videos store under /data/data/app_package/ path?

Read in some blogs like other apps cannot access /data/data/app_package path of different apps.

Is there any way to give access in android KitKat?

Comment: While it is not recommended, you can have the code of the owning app change the permission of the folder using either Java (ie, set Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE) or native APIs such as chmod(2).  Generally though, data you want to share should either be on the External Storage or exposed via a ContentProvider - some apps will refuse to *even try* to access things from another app's private folder *even when they have been granted such access by the operating system*.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with having root 'su' on the phone.

Alternatively you should put them in /sdcard/android/data/app_package/ or /sdcard/android/obb/app_package/ where sdcard is the internal storage in KitKat or Lollipop.

Comment: Not true.  Also, please don't assume what paths on the device will be.

Comment: I have a kitkat device and I know it mounts internal as /sdcard/ anyway I was trying to help you can downvote if you like. and about the /data/data/ I tried to access it and it indeed require a root. If you have a way please share with us.

Comment: As I said in the comment on the question itself, the owning app can grant access.  Downvoting is less productive than critiquing your answer in words.

Comment: Only because you don't have any where the owning app has set them to have public read and execute permission.  Note that even with this you won't be able to *browse* to them as /data itself lacks such permission.  But you can access contents which have been granted world permission, but using the full path.

Comment: Ok thanks for the new information. But why not storing it in android folder if user can read it anyway?

Comment: That's a good idea, but you should not **assume** the path of that folder, but rather discover it using the proper APIs at runtime.

Comment: I am not telling you to assume the path you can get it using getexternaldir or whatever but it is for sure that that would be the bath especially from kitkat and on, which prevents applications from writing to external sdcard except in the private directory